# "Filter failed" errors when attempting to print to newly installed Epson WF-M1030

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I am very new to Ubuntu (14.04) and have spent the past 3 days trying to get a printer to work.  Tried generic drivers using system settings and all five drivers downloaded from Epson support using CUPS with same result.  At best I get "filter failed" error when printing test page.  Is this just not meant to be?  Any suggestions appreciated, but please be aware I am not a technical user.

Comment: There is only one driver fot this printer on Epson site. Or two if count a generic driver. Please describe what and how did you install.

Comment: At this site (http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=20435&DSCCHK=d6e633a932b900a1089e5ad1e4933f87757e47a9) after I "accept" it displays: File name File size  
epson-inkjet-printer-201214w-1.0.0-1lsb3.2.i486.rpm 1,000.66 KB 
epson-inkjet-printer-201214w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb 994.1 KB 
epson-inkjet-printer-201214w-1.0.0-1lsb3.2.x86_64.rpm 1,023.08 KB 
epson-inkjet-printer-201214w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb 1 MB 
epson-inkjet-printer-201214w-1.0.0-1lsb3.2.src.rpm 1.53 MB

Comment: epson-inkjet-printer-201214w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb 1 MB 
epson-inkjet-printer-201214w-1.0.0-1lsb3.2.src.rpm 1.53 MB
  I used each in turn with the CUPS administrator add printer utility.  All appeared to work until I attempted to print a test page.    I'm using an older Compaq (HP) mini 110 if that is relevant. It is 32-bit with an Intel 945GME x86/MMX/SSE2.

Comment: That Epson model was a bit of a pain to set up in Windows as I recall.  Plan B is to email Ubuntu print jobs to myself and print from another device.  I don't expect to print very often and my phone and tablet have good apps for that.

Comment: You did it wrong. I will write an answer.

Comment: It looks like you did not INSTALL any driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to [Epson printer drivers site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX), search for your printer and download ONE deb file: epson-inkjet-printer-201214w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb if your system is 32-bit, or epson-inkjet-printer-201214w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb if your system is 64-bit.

Place this file to your Home directory and run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i epson*.deb
```

If system gives dependency errors, then run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

After that go to System Settings and install a new printer.

Comment: Outstanding! Followed your instructions (did need to run the dependency error thing) and my printer works.  And on the network even.  Didn't think that would be possible given that it was a little fiddly to install in Windows.  Thank you so much.  While we are on a roll, would a similar process work to install the 32-bit Broadcom driver at this site? https://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php  Or do I need to submit this question under a more relevant subject?

Comment: Spoke too soon re Broadcom.  There is a good explanation under "http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers..." but the author warns of installing after any other change such as using apt-get, etc.

Comment: You better click this question as 'solved' and ask a new one, if you need help with Broadcom.